# Removing the last row apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

This is a popular method of removing a row

```
public static void removeRow(Sheet sheet, int rowIndex) {
    int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    if (rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < lastRowNum) {
        sheet.shiftRows(rowIndex + 1, lastRowNum, -1);
    }
    if (rowIndex == lastRowNum) {
        Row removingRow = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
        if (removingRow != null) {

        // to verify that I am dealing with the last row
            System.out.println(sheet.getRow(lastRowNum).getCell(0).toString() ; 
        // I created a unique string for the last row so that to make sure everything is ok

            sheet.removeRow(removingRow);  // does not always work
        }
    }
}
```

However for some reason the last row does not always gets removed. I double checked it with `System.out.println`

Has anybody encountered this ? How can I deal with it ?

Comment: I have tried same code various times... it seem working fine and giving expected result all the time. In case rowIndex value is something that is not allowing to pass any if condition, else removing all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing this:

int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;